# Позиционирование стрелок в слайдере

Tags: html, css

Сделал слайдер на сайте но не могу сделать так что бы стрелки были спозиционированы нормально по отношению к слайдеру. Съезжают в бок куда-то.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
 showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
 showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
 var i;
 var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

 if(n > slides.length){
  slideIndex = 1;
 }
 if(n< 1){
  slideIndex = slides.length;
 }
 for(i = 0; i<slides.length; i++){
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
 }
 for(i = 0; i < dots.length; i++){
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active","");
 }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/*Slider*/

.slideshow-container{
 max-width: 900px;
 position: relative;
}
.prev, .next{
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: auto;
 margin-top: -22px;
 padding: 16px;
 color:white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
 border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next{
 right: 8px;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.mySlides{
 text-align: center;
 max-height: 700px;
}
.text{
 color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 90px;
}
.dot{
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 13px;
 width: 13px;
 margin: 0 2px;
 background-color: #bbb;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: background-color:0.6s ease;

}
.active, .dot:hover{
 background-color: #717171;

}
.fade{
 -webkit-animation-name: fade;
 -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
 animation-name:fade;
 animation-duration:1s;
}
/*@-webkit-keyframes fade{
 0%{opacity:0.4;}
 100%{opacity:1;}
}*/
@keyframes fade{
 0%{opacity:0.4;}
 100%{opacity:1;}
}

/*End Slider*/
```

```html
 <div class="slidershow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   <div class="numbertext">1/3</div>
   <img src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
   <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas iusto aspernatur quo.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   <div class="numbertext">2/3</div>
   <img src="img/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
   <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias temporibus nihil, quaerat!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
   <div class="numbertext">3/3</div>
   <img src="img/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
   <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto eaque voluptatibus, doloribus!</div>
  </div>
  <a onclick="plusSlides(-1)" class="prev">&#10094</a>
  <a onclick="plusSlides(1)" class="next">&#10095</a>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div style="text-align:center;">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>

 </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скопировал твой код, добавил картинки... ничего ни куда не съежает, что именно тебе не нравится? опиши проблему нормально, что не так и как ты хочешь чтобы было

Comment: @Air Да я забил просто стрелки убрал и всё